# Is there a way to paste text from a buffer into your command using just the keyboard?

Tags: command-line, register

Sometimes I copy text from the buffer in VM and I want to use it in an editor command.  Is there some way to paste it from a register into the command text using only the keyboard?

Comment: Note that this question is actually asking about "registers".  "Buffer" means something else entirely in both vi and vim.

Comment: @wildcard Well ya take the text from the buffer to a register and then paste it into the command.

Comment: Actually I found out since I wrote the above comment that [the POSIX specifications for `vi`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html#) use the term "buffer" rather than "register".  I still think using the term "register" is better, though, to distinguish from the "edit buffer."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep, just like in insert mode: `Ctrl-R` followed by the register name, or `"` for the default one (i.e. `Ctrl-R "`). See `:h c_CTRL-R`.